# instanceof operator and this.constructor.name showing parent class name even it is child class in typescipt

Tags: typescript, inheritance, extends, instanceof

Instanceof operator and this.constructor.name showing parent class name even it is child class in typescipt.

I defined a class that extends default typescript error class

```
export default class ExpressError extends Error {
    message: string;
    status: number;
    error_id: number;
    no_db_store: boolean;
    name = "ExpressError";

    constructor(message: string, status: number, error_id = 0, no_db_store = true) {
        super();
        this.message = message;
        this.status = status;
        this.error_id = error_id;
        this.no_db_store = no_db_store;

        console.log('\n\n\n\nthis.constructor.name = ' + this.constructor.name); // prints "Error"
        console.log('new.target.name = ' + new.target.name); // prints "ExpressError"
        console.log('\n\n\n\n');
    }
}
```

Whenever I throw a new `ExpressError` and try to get the class name it shows "Error" not "ExpressError". Furthermore, it enters first else if. how can I know if I made `throw new Error` vs `throw new ExpressError`?

this is the code where I try to get the class name:

```
        catch (e: unknown) {
            let structured_error: {
                [key: string]: string | undefined | number | boolean
            } = {};

            // this line prints "Error"
            console.log(e.constructor.name)

            // checking if this is a sequelize error
            if (e instanceof  UniqueConstraintError) {
                structured_error = {
                    message: e.errors[0].message,
                    status: 403,
                    stack: e.stack,
                };
            } 

            // this is the matched condition
            else if (e instanceof Error) {
                structured_error = {
                    message: e.message,
                    stack: e.stack,
                };
            }
            else if (e instanceof ExpressError) {
                structured_error = {
                    message: e.message,
                    stack: e.stack,
                    status: e.status,
                    no_db_store: e.no_db_store
                };
            }
       }
```

Comment: Why not use `e.name`? Besides, the `instanceOf` keyword is enough for your case. Also, see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Error#custom_error_types

Comment: yeah, i defined the name property as a workaround but I am trying to figure out why it is not showing the correct class name in the first place : )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The order of your `if`/`else` statements is incorrect. You need to try to match the most specific type first, as an object that is an instance of `ExpressError` is also an instance of `Error`.

See the following example:

```
class ExpressError extends Error {
    message: string;
    status: number;
    error_id: number;
    no_db_store: boolean;
    name = "ExpressError";

    constructor(message: string, status: number, error_id = 0, no_db_store = true) {
        super();
        this.message = message;
        this.status = status;
        this.error_id = error_id;
        this.no_db_store = no_db_store;

        console.log('\n\n\n\nthis.constructor.name = ' + this.constructor.name);
        console.log('new.target.name = ' + new.target.name);
        console.log('\n\n\n\n');
    }
}

function testError() {
    try {
        throw new ExpressError('message', 0);
    } catch (e: any) {
        console.log(e.constructor.name);

        if (e instanceof ExpressError) {
            console.log("Instance of ExpressError");
        }

        if (e instanceof Error) {
            console.log("Instance of Error");
        }
    }
}

testError();
```

<sup>[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=37&ssc=13&pln=1&pc=1#code/MYGwhgzhAECiAeAHATgUyrZyD2zqvgBdUA7AExkxzwG8AoaR6AW3QjAHNUAuaCQ5AEsSHANwMm-MIQCuEXiRnMARqmTim+LLgD6gsgqWr1ExiWw6yynf1w9oy7NhCowJDUxJhW0ALzQAIgQUNipcAPFTaGBsEn5kGWBCXAAKVihOe3jhDgAaPkJpOUMVNXy1aj0yP2gABnzzS2tbNBqBGVQASmh6TU0IGUQ1FM6PPuhCAAtBCAA6dPYuGoXMsb6pmdmpWRh-bbk1zQ25it19GtPkKsOmY9nGqxtk1v8H5ufUSPHGGLjnVFmIGwHBSAHIADokSHQkh3X7xRLPe7eVA1UHQADUE2mc3h7SSuGRrFGUU08P+gOBYJIqAA7rNCsguIQiaj-OisTT6YzmaySd9orEIBSgSCIVCJZDQfymABfOjyugAMxkJCSgliE3QhDCyBGPSiAgAngaBVMcLToFy4Eg0BhtHrQSsuKD8rUZYxZdFpMBJtAUvY3Ebur1vuSXJSQQC8QkCcg+V9voIlf7UcIpGrUNgU8E7RBdSHSWGhSKqQEAJJxQqZ6DZm0he3UAIevqKgXJ1PQdPV4BZnMOwsCskliOilIVqtuXu1-tNluaeULhV0OjEfi6kaiIA)</sup>

The rest of the behavior you describe I can't reproduce. The constructor name is correctly printed.

Comment: I tried to change the order of else if and it is still not working.

Comment: Please provide a [mre]. At least I provided a playground link where you can verify my claims.

Comment: Thank you for the example, this catch is inside a function wrapper for express middle-wares. When I tried reproducing the example while removing express parameters it worked fine. so I think the problem lies withing express error itself. if I put the whole code it will require you to run express server. So, I will try to find the error within express error handler itself.

Comment: The problem was that tsc-watch wasn't reading the ts-config.json which lead to compilation to a very old version of js which resulted in the strange class behavior. I managed tsc-watch to read the ts-config and now it works fine. thank you :  )

Answer (score 1):

Here your error variable is both an Error and an ExpressError, it will return true for both of your statements. It is your checking order that is wrong. If you want to differenciate them you should test the derived classes first.

so you should do it like this :

```typescript
            //match childrens first
            if (e instanceof ExpressError) {
                structured_error = {
                    message: e.message,
                    stack: e.stack,
                    status: e.status,
                    no_db_store: e.no_db_store
                };
            }
            //then finish with the parent
            else if (e instanceof Error) {
                structured_error = {
                    message: e.message,
                    stack: e.stack,
                };
            }
```

Comment: I tried to change the order of else if and it is still not working.